# Google Map route does not show up

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using `Google Map V2` and I am trying to show route on `google map` through `Polygon` Options and also tried through `PolyLine` Options.

I have gone through lots of answers on `stack overflow` but its no use,route does not show up. My code is as below:

```
 points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    PolygonOptions lineOptions = new PolygonOptions();
    for (int i = 0; i < directionEntityMain.getOverview_polyline().size(); i++) {
        LatLng position = directionEntityMain.getOverview_polyline().get(i);
        points.add(position);
    }

    lineOptions.addAll(points);
    lineOptions.strokeWidth(2);
    lineOptions.strokeColor(Color.RED);
    googleMap.addPolygon(lineOptions);
```

Comment: Usually the polylines comes in an encoded string. You need to convert them in to LatLng before use. Are you sure you are doing that in your code?

Comment: I have posted link here for draw path you can check there hope its helps you.

Comment: @MuchOverflow yes i have decoded the string into LatLng array and directionEntity contains my that LatLng array.

Comment: Then it is better to debug your code. Check whether you actually received any route data and that the map is positioned / zoomed enough for you to see the drawn route. Also make sure to add the route after map is loaded. You can use OnMapLoaded callback for this purpose

Comment: @VishalHalani hey Vishal yes i have used drawPath code but it didn't worked

Comment: @MuchOverflow I m adding markers just before drawing route i am able to view the markers though but route doesn't show up. I have checked on debug the LatLng array gets inflated well.

Answer (score 0):

**Try from this code**

**First of all we will get source and destination points between which we have to draw route. Then we will pass these attribute to below function.**

```
 public String makeURL (double sourcelat, double sourcelog, double destlat, double destlog ){
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
    urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
    urlString.append("?origin=");// from
    urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString
            .append(Double.toString( sourcelog));
    urlString.append("&destination=");// to
    urlString
            .append(Double.toString( destlat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append(Double.toString( destlog));
    urlString.append("&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true");
    urlString.append("&key=YOUR_API_KEY");
    return urlString.toString(); }
```

**This function will make the url that we will send to get Direction API response. Then we will parse that response . The parser class is**

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";
// constructor
public JSONParser() {
}
public String getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        json = sb.toString();
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    return json;

}}
```

**This parser will return us string. We will call it like that.**

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();  String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

**Now we will send this string to our drawpath function. The drawpath function is**

```
public void drawPath(String  result) {

try {
        //Tranform the string into a json object
       final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
       JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
       JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
       JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
       String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
       List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);
       Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                                .addAll(list)
                                .width(12)
                                .color(Color.parseColor("#05b1fb"))//Google maps blue color
                                .geodesic(true)
                );
       /*
       for(int z = 0; z<list.size()-1;z++){
            LatLng src= list.get(z);
            LatLng dest= list.get(z+1);
            Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude), new LatLng(dest.latitude,   dest.longitude))
            .width(2)
            .color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));
        }
       */
} 
catch (JSONException e) {

}}
```

**Above code will draw the path on mMap. The code of decodePoly is**

```
private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
int lat = 0, lng = 0;

while (index < len) {
    int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
    do {
        b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
        shift += 5;
    } while (b >= 0x20);
    int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
    lat += dlat;

    shift = 0;
    result = 0;
    do {
        b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
        shift += 5;
    } while (b >= 0x20);
    int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
    lng += dlng;

    LatLng p = new LatLng( (((double) lat / 1E5)),
             (((double) lng / 1E5) ));
    poly.add(p);
}

return poly;}
```

**As direction call may take time so we will do all this in Asynchronous task. My Asynchronous task was**

```
private class connectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
String url;
connectAsyncTask(String urlPass){
    url = urlPass;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching route, Please wait...");
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.show();
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    return json;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);   
    progressDialog.hide();        
    if(result!=null){
        drawPath(result);
    }
}}
```

Comment: it not working  LatLng src = directionEntityMain.getOverview_polyline().get(i);
            if ((i + 1) < directionEntityMain.getOverview_polyline().size() && directionEntityMain.getOverview_polyline().get(i + 1) != null) {
                dest = directionEntityMain.getOverview_polyline().get(i + 1);
                Polyline line = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude), new LatLng(dest.latitude, dest.longitude))
                        .width(2)
                        .color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));
            }

Comment: hey Vishal I have used drawPath method  code which you have commented out.  public void drawPath(String  result)

Comment: @Aditi please debug your code. you get exact code where you make mistake.

Comment: @Aditi https://blog.synyx.de/2010/06/routing-driving-directions-on-android-%E2%80%93-part-2-draw-the-route/

Comment: @Aditi ummm..you try blog link which i was sent??

Comment: will try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have mapped the JSON response of the Directions API to your `directionEntityMain` object, you can do the following to draw the route on the map

```
List<LatLng> points = decodePoly(directionEntityMain.getOverview_polyline()
                                                           .getPoints());
PolyLineOptions lineOptions = new PolyLineOptions()
                                    .addAll(points)
                                    .strokeWidth(2)
                                    .strokeColor(Color.RED);
googleMap.addPolyline(lineoptions);


//the decoder function
private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
```